# Is it possible to merge into a pull request

Tags: git, github

Let's I have two commits in a pull request; one is a descendant of another.  For example;

(descendant)

https://github.com/common-workflow-language/cwltool/commit/a42ef0604e1957c8c91fde26a2f939444df5009b

(parent)

https://github.com/common-workflow-language/cwltool/pull/64/commits/e2231e1d1eabffa68bcfdc2e0fbe2419a7204b07

How would one go about merging the descendant into the pull request?  Presumably I have to do something like pull the descendant into the parent and then re-commit?  I can't seem to get this working.  I've tried various approaches (i.e. cherry picking), and can't seem to do it right.  I appreciate your help and expertise.

Comment: Both of those links point to the same commit...

Comment: When you say pull request, do you mean branch?  A pull request is a github resource.  It's basically saying, "I want to merge branch A into branch B".  Pushing another commit to branch A will automatically make it show up on the github pull request, but it doesn't sound like that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pull request is just a request to merge one branch into another. You can update a pull request at any time by changing the commit the source branch for that PR is pointing to. So to merge the "descendant" pull request into its parent, just merge the source branch for the descendant pull request into the source branch for the parent PR.

E.g. if you have `pr1`, the source branch for the parent PR, and `pr2`, the branch for the descendant PR:

[image: Commit graph with pr1 and pr2]

Just checkout `pr1`, run `git merge pr2`, then push with `git push origin pr1`:

[image: After merge and push]

That should update the PR in GitHub. [Try it out in Learn Git Branching!](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/?gist_level_id=be6d08de5273c85e0e151769d6891079)

Comment: This is incredible Ajedi32.  Thank you.  I believe you are correct.  This was eventually achieved by a technique similar to what you specified.  The commands used to add and execute the push (from local working copy) were as follows (for this cherry-pick was used as opposed to a merge).  
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4814221a475216abf5b3b478e14c5f6c